# How to calculate the number of random variables in every intevals in R?

Tags: r

I create an interval of[0,1], I split my interval in many Under intervals,  I put some random variable, I need to compare in every interval how many variable I have in my under interval, I add the sum of variable to a vector, the size of the vector is the number of my  under_intervals, finally, my results is this vector which contains the  sum of variables in each under-intervals:

```
Q<- runif(120, min=0, max=1)
y<-sort(Q)
x<-seq(0,1, by=1/1200)

for(j in 1:length(x)-1){
  for(i in 1:length(y)){
 somme[j]= ifelse(y[i] >= x[j] & y[i]<= x[j+1],1,0)
  }
}
```

I am a beginner with R,  so i don't find the best solution  that I wait.

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cut` function is designed to break numeric vectors into groups. You can then use dplyr to aggregate the sums.

```
library(dplyr)
Q <- runif(120, min=0, max=1)
intervals <- data.frame(interval = cut(Q, breaks = seq(0, 1, 1/1200)), Q) %>%
  group_by(interval) %>%
  summarize( sum = sum(Q))
```

If you would like to keep the `0`s as well you can use the `split` to create a list of those interval splits and then perform a sum with `sapply`.

```
sapply(split(Q, f = cut(Q, breaks = seq(0, 1, 1/1200))), sum)
```